# Adding the values in a Coulmn using Powershell Only

Tags: powershell

I have a problem in adding the values in column to get a total sum count. I have built a query and it returns the values of the total time of a particular assignment. The output looks something like :

```
                 Total Time in Queue
            0Days0 Hours 10Minutes 16Seconds
            0Days0 Hours 20Minutes 36Seconds
            0Days0 Hours 35Minutes 46Seconds
```

I want to get the total time in Queue for the particular ticket. I am not able to add the time in the individual rows,I think this is because of the uneven pattern of the time showed in the 'Total Time in Queue' column.

Could somebody help me with this please?

NOTE : I need to accomplish this using **ONLY** PowerShell.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this sort of transformation using the `-replace` feature.  For example:

`PS> '1Days0 Hours 124Minutes 16Seconds' -replace '\s*([0-9]+)\s*Days\s*([0-9]+)\s*Hours\s*([0-9]+)\s*Minutes\s*([0-9]+)\s*Seconds', '($1 * 86400) + ($2 * 3600) + ($3 * 60) + $4' | Invoke-Expression`

The above yields the answer `93856`. I've added `\s*` inbetween each bit in the regular expression as this means "zero or more whitespace characters" to parse the weird spacing you have.

If you are processing a set of results, you can create a new column with the following:

`... | Select-Object @{Expression={$_.'Total Time in Queue' -replace '\s*([0-9]+)\s*Days\s*([0-9]+)\s*Hours\s*([0-9]+)\s*Minutes\s*([0-9]+)\s*Seconds', '($1 * 86400) + ($2 * 3600) + ($3 * 60) + $4' | Invoke-Expression};Label="TotalTimeInSeconds"}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using parsing as `[TimeSpan]` objects :

```
$data = "0Days0 Hours 10Minutes 16Seconds","0Days0 Hours 20Minutes 36Seconds","0Days0 Hours 35Minutes 46Seconds
$times = $data | % {$_ -replace 'Days',':' -replace ' Hours ',':'  -replace 'Minutes ',':' -replace 'seconds',''}
$times | % {[TimeSpan]$sum=0}{$value=[TimeSpan]::ParseExact($_, 'd\:h\:mm\:ss', $null);$sum+=$value}{$sum}
```